# Can't make sens out of javascript event and functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Here is the code that works as-is, a classic onBeforeUnLoad event, in the `<script type="text/jscript">` tag of my ASP page :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        a = 1;
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault = true;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = "do you wish to save?";
}
```

Now, two issues i'm experiencing when wanting to do something more complex :

1. I want this to appear only once at all cost :

   ```
   var a = 0;

   window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

       if (a == 0) {
           a = 1;
           e = e || window.event;
           e.preventDefault = true;
           e.cancelBubble = true;
           e.returnValue = "Wish to save?";
       }
   }

    //Does not work...
   ```
2. I want it to be able to run this other function that **works** when not combined with the first :

   ```
   comfirmExit = function(){
       if (confirm("Wish to save?") == true) {
       document.getElementById('<%= btnEnregistrer.ClientID %>').click();
       }
    }
    // works, but not when combine to the first function
   ```

I tried to put this all together... I want the unload event to make my confirm box function run :

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

        if (a == 0) {
            a = 1;
        comfirmExit = function(){
        if (confirm("Wish to save?") == true) {
        document.getElementById('<%= btnEnregistrer.ClientID %>').click();
            }
        }
    }
```

And now I realize I'm far from being an expert of javascript...

Comment: The `beforeUnload` event won't run any obtrusive Javascript for the user (ie `alert`, `confirm` etc).

Comment: You cannot on modern browser,  you can only returns string from this event

Comment: and some browsers will even ignore the returned string and only show default message. My approach is... *if you are trying to do important things in unload...it's too late*

Comment: also preventDefault is a function not a boolean property

Comment: But there must be a way to do it an other way then what i'm trying... seriously how can someone make a dessent "Do you want to save before leaving?" message... It's impossible ?

Comment: honestly no...because it got so abused over the years you are very limited what you can do due to security and user experience

Comment: I saw that, even my browser always offers me to bloque these

Comment: some browsers will accept a different message returned...not all. IE for example did up until at least IE10 i think...not sure about newer versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `beforeunload` event won't run any obtrusive Javascript for the user (ie `alert`, `confirm` etc).

But there is an workaround, the steps should be something like:

- Create a boolean flag to check if the user has canceled the exiting of your page (default `false`).
- Create the `beforeunload` event handler, and check if the game is not
  saved.

  - If it was already saved, then, you do nothing, and let the user go
  - But if it was not, then you change that boolean flag to `true`.
- You keep an interval dirty-checking if that variable is `true`, and at anytime it is, you save the game for the user, and then set this variable to `false` again.

So, doing that, you'll ensure the user always see a message if they're leaving without saving, and if they cancel the exiting, the game will be automatically saved, making the next try pretty smooth.

Take a look at the example below. To test it, open your console, click on `Run`. Then, try to click on `Run` again, and you'll see an exiting message. If you confirm it, your console won't show anything. But if you cancel it, then, you'll be kept in the page, then you try to click `Run` again, and you'll see that no message will appear, but the console will log `true`.

```js
(function() {
  var game = { saved: false };
  var canceled = false;
  
  setInterval(function() {
    if (canceled) {
      game.saved = true;
      canceled = false;
    }
  }, 100);
  
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (!game.saved) {
      canceled = true;
      return 'Are you sure?';
    }
    else {
      console.log(game.saved);
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Pretty interesting workaround ! I guest that's the best answer there could be, but I must admit that a little amount of postbacks prevent it from working correctly on my pages, and that's my own fault. Well... think i'll just accept that onbeforeUnload is dead.